# convert multiply lines between pattern to a comma separated string

Tags: bash, design-patterns, awk, sed, multiline

I need help in processing data from STDIN (data is taken from another file with 'tail -f' plus grepped to filter out garbage). There are several lines between patterns:

```
    <DN>  589</DN>
    <DD>03.12.2014</DD>
    <ST>   </ST>
    <STC>0</STC>
    <STT>0</STT>
    <PU>5</PU>
    <OT>01</OT>
    <DSN></DSN>
    <NRA>40807,40820,426,30231,40818,30230</NRA>
    <GR>300 000-00&#13;&#10</GR>
```

then next block with DN/GR starts

I need to convert lines between  and  to a single line, comma-separated:

```
<DN>  589</DN>,<DD>03.12.2014</DD>,<ST>   </ST>,<STC>0</STC>,<STT>0</STT>,<PU>5</PU>,<OT>01</OT>,<DSN></DSN>,<NRA>40807,40820,426,30231,40818,30230</NRA>,<GR>300 000-00&#13;&#10</GR>
```

I need a one-liner with awk or sed or perl to do it and put result to STDOUT.
I've tried to do it, but failed due to lack of experience. Also tried to google and didn't find a working solution.

Comment: `tr '\n' ',' < file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -nr '/<DN>/,/<GR>/{ H; /<GR>/{ g; s%\n%,%g; s%^,%%; p; s%.*%%; h }; }' <<'EOSEQ'
<DN>  589</DN>
<DD>03.12.2014</DD>
<STC>0</STC>
<GR>300 000-00&#13;&#10</GR>
<DN>900</DN>
<DD>20.11.2014</DD>
<OT>01</OT>
<NRA>40807,40820,426,30231,40818,30230</NRA>
<GR>300 000-00&#13;&#10</GR>
EOSEQ
```

SED one-liner, as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

```
whatever..| awk '{sub(/^\s*/,"");printf "%s%s",$0,(/\/GR>\s*$/?"\n":",")}'
```

this line does:

- remove the leading spaces from each line
- join all line with sep `,` till the block end `/GR>`
- if you have x data blocks, it gives you x long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you could do the following:

```
awk '{printf ("%s,", $NF)}' test.txt ##Will have comma at the end which may/may not be ok for you.
```

Comment: apart from the trailing comma, you cut the beginning tags off if there were spaces in the tag text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one in sed.

```
sed -r ':loop ;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\1,\2/ ; t loop ' file name.
```